# How to display specific object from a database in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to display specific object (example:name) from a database, like third from a list. How to do it correctly?

closest i got was this piece of code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ListName.First().Name)
```

But it will only show first name from the list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.